# Using values in a range as a variable

Tags: vba, excel

Instead of hard coding the value to be looked up ("1234"), I would like to use a range of values, on a separate worksheet("Items") to use as the search criteria.

I would also like to substitute that same value for the destination sheet.

For example, the first value in the range could be "8754", I would like the code to look for this value then paste the columns, A,B,C,F and the cell containing the value onto the worksheet "8754". (I have all of the worksheets created already)

TIA

```
Sub Test()
Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1") 'Sheet with data to check for value
For Each Cell In .Range("H1:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
    pos = InStr(Cell.Value, "1234")
    If pos > 0 Then
        NextFreeRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, 
"A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
         'get the next empty row to paste data to
        .Range("A" & Cell.Row & ",B" & Cell.Row & ",C" & Cell.Row & ",F" & 
Cell.Row & "," & Cell.Address).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & NextFreeRow)
        End If
    Next Cell
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the range on `Worksheets("Items")` a column?

Comment: It is right now, but that is not a requirement

Comment: Just so I have it correct - Somewhere you have a range of cells containing values.  You want to work your way through these values and see if they also appear in column `H` of `Sheet1`.  If it does then copy the values from columns `A`, `B`, `C` and `F` on that row in `Sheet1` and paste into the next available row on `Sheet2`, or is it paste onto the next available row on a sheet with the same name as the value you just looked up?

Comment: Yes, paste it onto a brand new sheet with the sheet name the same as the value it is looking for from the range.  ie. So rage value #1 = 8754 copy to worksheet named 8754  (fyi, I have all of the worksheets created already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses `FIND` rather than `FILTER` to copy the correct rows.
The `Main` procedure defines the range you're searching and which values will be searched for.  The `FindValues` procedure finds the value and copies it to the correct sheet.

This assumes that `Sheet3!A1:A3` contains a unique list of values to be searched for and the these values can be found in `Sheet1!H:H`.
It also assumes that all sheets already exist.

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim rToFind As Range
    Dim rValue As Range
    Dim rSearchRange As Range

    With ThisWorkbook

        'Update to the range being searched.
        With .Worksheets("Sheet1")
            Set rSearchRange = .Range("H1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp))
        End With

        'Update to the range containing the values to be searched for.
        Set rToFind = .Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A3")

    End With

    'Passe each of the values to be searched to the FindValues procedure.
    For Each rValue In rToFind
        FindValues rValue, rSearchRange
    Next rValue


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'    Alternative method to look for hard-coded values.
'    `ValuesToFind` in FindValues procedure will needed changing to a Variant.
'
'    Dim vAlternativeSearch As Variant
'    Dim vAlternativeValue As Variant
'    vAlternativeSearch = Array(1475, 1683, 219)
'
'    For Each vAlternativeValue In vAlternativeSearch
'        FindValues vAlternativeValue, rSearchRange
'    Next vAlternativeValue

End Sub

Public Sub FindValues(ValueToFind As Range, RangeToSearch As Range)

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress
    Dim rLastUsedCell As Range

    'Find the next available row on the referenced sheet.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(ValueToFind))
        Set rLastUsedCell = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Offset(1)
    End With

    With RangeToSearch

        'Find the first value.
        Set rFound = .Find(What:=ValueToFind, _
                           After:=RangeToSearch.Cells(RangeToSearch.Cells.Count), _
                           LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        'If the first value exists then remember the address, copy the cells to the
        'correct sheet and look for the next row with the same value.  Stop when
        'it reaches the first address again.
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAddress = rFound.Address
            Do
                'You may have to muck around with this to get the correct range to copy.
                'If rFound is in column H this will copy columns B:D and F.
                Union(rFound.Offset(, -6).Resize(, 3), rFound.Offset(, -2)).Copy Destination:=rLastUsedCell
                Set rLastUsedCell = rLastUsedCell.Offset(1)
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

#### Edit 1:

You say the worksheets already exists, but in your comment you say put it in a brand new sheet.
To add a new sheet add this function:

```
Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional WrkBk As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    If WrkBk Is Nothing Then
        Set WrkBk = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = WrkBk.Worksheets(SheetName)
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

and then add this code directly after the variable declaration in the `FindValues` procedure:

```
Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
If Not WorkSheetExists(CStr(ValueToFind)) Then
    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    wrkSht.Name = CStr(ValueToFind)
End If
```

## Edit 2:

This updated code searches columns Q:Z, returns the values from A:L as well as the found cell.
To update from the original code I had to change `rSearchRange` to look from Q1 to column 26, and update the Copy/Paste line to return the correct range.

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim rToFind As Range
    Dim rValue As Range
    Dim rSearchRange As Range

    With ThisWorkbook

        'Update to the range being searched.
        With .Worksheets("Data")
            Set rSearchRange = .Range("Q1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 26).End(xlUp))
        End With

        'Update to the range containing the values to be searched for.
        Set rToFind = .Worksheets("Items").Range("A1:A2")

    End With

    'Passe each of the values to be searched to the FindValues procedure.
    For Each rValue In rToFind
        FindValues rValue, rSearchRange
    Next rValue

End Sub

Public Sub FindValues(ValueToFind As Range, RangeToSearch As Range)

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress
    Dim rLastUsedCell As Range

    'Find the next available row on the referenced sheet.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(ValueToFind))
        Set rLastUsedCell = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Offset(1)
    End With

    With RangeToSearch

        'Find the first value.
        Set rFound = .Find(What:=ValueToFind, _
                           After:=RangeToSearch.Cells(RangeToSearch.Cells.Count), _
                           LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        'If the first value exists then remember the address, copy the cells to the
        'correct sheet and look for the next row with the same value.  Stop when
        'it reaches the first address again.
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAddress = rFound.Address
            Do
                'Parent of RangeToSeach range which will be the Data worksheet.
                With .Parent
                    'Copy columns A:L (columns 1 to 12) and the found cell.
                    Union(.Range(.Cells(rFound.Row, 1), .Cells(rFound.Row, 12)), rFound).Copy Destination:=rLastUsedCell
                End With
                Set rLastUsedCell = rLastUsedCell.Offset(1)
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)

            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you! Is there a way to also copy the cell that contained the data that was searched for? So I actually need the cells from columns A:L from the Data worksheet and the cell containing the text string from the range being searched:Q1:Z100. So rather than just looking at one column(H), search the range Q1:Z100 then copy those found cells to the worksheet.  Thank you again for this!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean.  It's easy enough to copy extra data  from the search range (`ValueToFind` in my code).  A reference to that cell is passed around, not just the value so to copy extra data you'd just need to add `ValueToFind.Resize(, 12).Copy Destination:=rLastUsedCell.Offset(, 4)` after the line that does the first copy/paste.  You mention a `Data` worksheet in your comment - you haven't mentioned that in your post, but you have mentioned a sheet called `Items` - apologies, that is the equivalent of `Sheet3` in the code.  Where does `Q1:Z100` come into it?

Comment: lol, no problem.  Just looked at your profile - you've got a title of _Director_ so wouldn't expect all the required information first time round :D

Comment: Worksheets: "Data" this is where the values to be searched live. I need to search range Q1:Z100 on this sheet.  Sheet "Items" contains the search criteria in column A, and the other sheets are named after each cell in the search criteria range. Other sheet names are "8475", "9999" etc. I need the search to look at Column A on the Items sheet, search for the value in cell A1, say "9999". Search the range Q1:Z100 on the Data sheet then if it finds the value in row 1 on the Data sheet, copy cells A1:L1 and the cell in range Q1:Z100 that contained the search data to the worksheet named "9999"

Comment: So "8475" could appear anywhere in the range Q1:Z100.  Is it possible that two values from the `Item` sheet may appear on the same row in the `Data` sheet?  e.g. "8475" is in `Q20` and "9999" is in `V20`?  I don't think this will stop the code - it will just copy the values to both sheets.

Comment: Yes, the values can appear anywhere in the range Q1:Z100. Yes, two values from the Items range could appear in two different cells in that range as you have stated.

Comment: I tried the new code, but now nothing is being copied at all.

Comment: My set up of the workbook was:  In the `Items` sheet I have the values **4175** and **412** in cells `A1:A2`.  In the `Data` sheet I have values in cells `A1:L100` and `Q1:Z100` - in this last range I have randomly placed the values **4175** and **412** in various cells.  I have two blank sheets called `4175` and `412`  When I run the code the data from columns A:L are copied across as well as the value in the found cell.  Is this similar to your setup?

Comment: Similar, but the values being searched are buried in text strings, not just numeric values in the cell. The value of cell Q40 can be something like:  "2018 - Cookbook - Item - 4175"

Comment: That's odd - it found "2018 - Cookbook - Item - 4175" fine when I told it to search for "4175".  The `LookAt:=xlPart` in the `Find` code does that - you sure yours doesn't say `LookAt:=xlWhole`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but mine is not working. I copied all of your code from the Edit 2 box, pasted it into the code on my Data sheet and tried to run it, and nothing happens. (Your first code did paste some data for me) I apologize for not being able to offer more help.

Comment: Try pasting it into a new module rather than the code sheet attached to the `Data` sheet.  If that doesn't work try adding some watches and watching them as you step through the code using F8 - to do this choose _Watch Window_ from the _View_ menu, right click and select `Add Watch`.  Add things like `RangeToSearch.Address` and change the `Procedure` drop-down to `FindValues`, click in the `Main` procedure and start tapping F8 to step through the code.  Make sure all variables are returning expected values.

Comment: That'll be it then - it should be `$Q$1:$Z$100`.  In the `Main` procedure is this line:  `Set rSearchRange = .Range("Q1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 26).End(xlUp))`  It uses column Z (26) to find the last row.  Change it to `Set rSearchRange = .Range("Q1", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Row, 26))` - this uses column S (19) to find the last row.  Change the `19` to a column that contains values in each row... or hardcode `Set rSearchRange = .Range("Q1:Z100")`.

Comment: VOILA!  Thank you so much, for the answer and for being so patient. You really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long
    Dim luArr As Variant, luVal As Variant, r As String, itm As Variant, itmRow As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")       'Sheet with data to check for value
    Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Items")      'LookUp values
    luArr = ws3.UsedRange.Columns("A")              'LookUp column
    lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim findRng As Range, copyRng As Range, toRng As Range, fr As Long
    Set findRng = ws1.Range("H1:H" & lr1)

    On Error Resume Next    'Expected error: sheet not found
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each luVal In luArr
        Set ws2 = Nothing
        Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(luVal)    'Copy to
        If ws2 Is Nothing Then
            Err.Clear
        Else
            itm = Application.Match(luVal, findRng, 0)
            If Not IsError(itm) Then
                findRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & luVal & "*"
                fr = IIf(findRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count = 1, 1, 2)
                With ws1.UsedRange
                    Set copyRng = .Range("A" & fr & ":C" & lr1)
                    Set copyRng = Union(copyRng, .Range("F" & fr & ":F" & lr1))
                    Set copyRng = Union(copyRng, .Range("H" & fr & ":H" & lr1))
                End With
                lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                copyRng.Copy
                ws2.Cells(lr2, 1).PasteSpecial
                findRng.AutoFilter
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Sheet1

[image: Sheet1]

Items

[image: Items]

Before (Sheet A1, A2, and A3)

[image: A1]
[image: A2]
[image: A3]

After

[image: A1]
[image: A2]
[image: A3]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, one thing I need would be rather than specifying "Sheet2", I would like to use the same variable from the "Items" list as the name of the worksheet to copy to. ie.  If the value in the range is 8475, then it should paste to worksheet 8475. If the value is 9999 then it should paste to worksheet 9999.  Sorry if I am not explaining this correctly.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple repeating values on Sheet1. The previous code worked perfectly, but I wanted to replace the hard coded 1234 with the range variable.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. BTW, the values I am searching for are embedded in a text string. so the 8475 would be in a cell where the cell value could be "2018 - Cookbook - Item 8475"

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but the code isn't doing anything. My original code was moving the selected search fields to the indicated sheets, but now nothing is being copied at all.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but nothing is working for me. I have worksheets named: "Data", "Items","8596" and the first value in the range in column A on the Items sheet is "8596". There is a string of text in column Q on the "Data" sheet that contains the text "8596". When I run the code, nothing gets copied to sheet "8596"

Comment: So `Sheet1` is called `Data`?

Comment: yes, that is the sheet containing the values to be searched

Comment: I updated the code (changed sheet name from `Sheet1` to `Data`)